# CLion debug missing breakpoints

Tags: debugging, clion

I am running CLion under Ubuntu 20.10. This is a new install. I've run CLion successfully in the past.

I have set a breakpoint, but it is changing to a grey "not" sign when I run. I looked it up https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/using-breakpoints.html#line-breakpoints and it says this happens when the code is not executable, which is not the problem...

[image]

Or when "some debugging symbols are missing." I don't know what this means. I tried searching for how to load them and found many links that really don't help.

I am set up for gdb and g++. Here is the output from my build:

```
====================[ Build | all | Debug ]=====================================
/opt/clion-2021.1.1/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/thomas/CLionProjects/processcontroller-test/cmake-build-debug --target all -- -j 6
[ 28%] Built target ProcessControllerTest_lib
[ 34%] Built target gtest
[ 62%] Built target ProcessControllerTest_run
[ 74%] Built target gtest_main
[ 74%] Built target gmock
[ 80%] Built target gmock_main
[100%] Built target ProcessControllerTest_tst

Build finished
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problems seem to have something to do with G+ plus version 10.3.0. I installed G+ + 9 and changed out my compiler and the break points started hitting. I have informed jetbrains.

Update, per JetBrains, added the following to my cmake:

```
add_compile_options(-gdwarf-4)
```

and am now able to run with 10.3.0. Hope this helps someone else.